# Get the User Filter value in the Dashboard (Zoho Analytics)

Tags: sql, data-analysis, dashboard, zoho, zoho-deluge

I built a dashboard in Zoho Analytics with different reports, tables, and widgets in it. The dashboard has one user filter and it's a date filter.

I'm happy to try Deluge script, SQL, or any other way to achieve this.

Scenario: The user set the date range on the dashboard to "Nov 1, 2023 - Nov 30, 2023".
Start Date: Nov 1, 2023
End Date: Nov 30, 2023

I need to have a way to obtain this date values "Nov 1, 2023 - Nov 30, 2023".

My goal is to calculate the number of days difference of the End Date and another date that I have in my data table.

Please note that the user filter is only available in the Dashboard web view, it's not available in the individual report.

Thank you in advance.

I tried using SQL funtions and Deluge scripts